# F# Function The 'if' expression needs to have type 'unit' to satisfy context type requirement

Tags: f#

In the function doTransfer below I am getting the error:

The 'if' expression needs to have type 'unit' to satisfy context type requirements. It currently has type 'bool.  This error is on each line that ends in:

```
if xxxxxresult  = false then return false
```

Note - the variables assigned to clickTransferResult should always = a bool value.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  It should exit the function if the result is false at any point

```
    let clickTransferTab (page: IPage, dataId: string) = async {
        try 
            // Click Transfer tab
            let! selector = Async.AwaitTask(page.WaitForSelectorAsync("div[data-id='"+dataId+"'] a.t3"))
            do! Async.AwaitTask(selector.ClickAsync())
            return true
        with ex ->
            return false
    }

    let doTransfer (page: IPage,
                    dataId: string,
                    transferAmount: string,
                    bankAccountText: string) = async {
        try
            let! clickTransferResult = clickTransferTab(page,dataId) 
            if clickTransferResult = false then return false 
            
            let! selectBankresult = clickTransferTab(page,dataId) 
            if selectBankresult = false then return false 

            let! enterTransferResult = clickTransferTab(page,dataId) 
            if enterTransferResult = false then return false 

            let! reconcilResult = clickTransferTab(page,dataId) 
            if reconcilResult = false then return false 

            return true
        with ex ->
            return false
    }
```

Comment: Note that `return` does not mean the same thing in F# as it does in C#. It does return a value but it doesn't stop the rest of the function from running, which is why you need the `else`. It's only needed at all because you're inside an `async` computation expression.

Answer (score 3):

`if` in F# is an expression not a statement like other languages. For example, you can write:

```
let x = if x > 5 then true else false
```

`if` evaluates to a value, and is assigned to `x`. Either it will be `true` or `false` in this case. But there must be a value. Let's assume you would write.

```
let x = if x > 5 then true
```

what value should `x` have, if x is smaller then 5? This is not valid code at all. You alway must provide a value to both cases. Here you maybe want `false`, but you must write it explicitly

```
let x = if x > 5 then true else false
```

or in this case you could just write:

```
let x = x > 5
```

The only exception to this rule is if the `then` case returns the `unit` value. In this case, there only exists one value, so it will also return `unit` in the `else` branch.

`if` in F# is like the [Ternary Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) in other languages.

So you have to write something like this

```
let! clickTransferResult = clickTransferTab(page,dataId) 
if clickTransferResult = false then 
    return false 
else
    let! selectBankresult = clickTransferTab(page,dataId) 
    if selectBankresult = false then 
        return false 
    else
        let! enterTransferResult = clickTransferTab(page,dataId) 
        if enterTransferResult = false then 
            return false 
        else
            let! reconcilResult = clickTransferTab(page,dataId) 
            if reconcilResult = false then 
                return false
            else
                return true
```

Comment: Ok , wow I didn’t expect it to have to return a true and a false . I guess that is the difference between C# and F# (or one of them . 

I just added else to each erroring line , find it easier to read

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, you can use a little computation expression to avoid the nested `if-then-else` expressions:

```ml
type AsyncBoolBuilder() =
    member _.Return(flag : bool) =
        async { return flag }
    member _.Bind(aflag, f) =
        async {
            let! flag = aflag
            if flag then
                return! f flag
            else
                return false
        }

let asyncBool = new AsyncBoolBuilder()
```

Example usage:

```ml
let isEvenAsync n =
    async {
        let isEven = (n % 2 = 0)
        printfn "isEven %A: %A" n isEven
        return isEven
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    let final =
        asyncBool {
            let! flag4 = isEvenAsync 4
            let! flag5 = isEvenAsync 5
            let! flag6 = isEvenAsync 6
            return true
        } |> Async.RunSynchronously
    printfn "Final flag: %A" final
    0
```

Output:

```
isEven 4: true
isEven 5: false
Final flag: false
```

Note that `isEvenAsync 6` is never executed, because `isEvenAsync 5` is `false`.